# I am getting unwanted index value with the value i need

Tags: python, pandas

i am working on twitter data and have extracted the trending topics. i converted it into a dataframe name 'trend' and now i want to extract 'woeid' w.r.t to 'name' column but when i use below snippet i get index value also. i just want the 'woeid' and index value is causing me problem as i have to pass this value to api.trends_place.how and i only extract the 'woeid'

i also used ''' ID =trend['woeid'].loc[trend['name']=='Ottawa']''' but the result was same.

i also tried using axes but if i use '''ID.axes[0][0]''' it gives me index number and when i use '''ID.axes[1[0]''' or '''ID.axes[0]1] ''' it gives below error:

---

IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 ID.axes[0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRXPU.png)

E:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in **getitem**(self, key)
   2067 
   2068         if is_scalar(key):
-> 2069             return getitem(key)
   2070 
   2071         if isinstance(key, slice):

### IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1

'''ID =trend['woeid'][trend['name']=='Ottawa']'''
'''ID['woeid']'''

expected output should be ID = 3369
actual Output is 2 3369 here 2 is the index number.

DataFrame:

```
          country        countrycode   name         woeid
    0     none           none          worldwide    1
    1     Canada         CA            Winnipeg     2972
    2     Canada         CA            Ottawa       3369
    3     United Kingdom UK            London       3444
    4     Germany        GR            Berlin       3567
```

> on above DataFrame using '''ID
>   =trend['woeid'].loc[trend['name']=='Ottawa']'''  will give you :'2  3369', 
>     but i only want 3369 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
country = ['none','Canada','Canada','United Kingdom']
countrycode =  ['none','CA','CA','UK']
name = ['worldwide','mWinnipeg','Ottawa','London']
woeid = [1,2972,3369,3444]

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(zip(country,countrycode,name,woeid),columns = ['country','countrycode','name','woeid'])
```

there are multiple ways

```
df.loc[df['name']=='Ottawa', 'woeid'].iloc[0]

df.loc[df['name']=='Ottawa', 'woeid'].item()

df[df['name']=='Ottawa']['woeid'].values

#using query method
df.query('name == "Ottawa"')['woeid'].iloc[0]
```